# Api working in browser but not in fetch javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using openweather api to create a weather application but my fetch api call is not working. My api call is working in browser but not in my code.

```
handleSubmit(){
    var city = this.state.city;
    var url = 'api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=67deb752d27d411a9ac101935181007&q=' + city;
    console.log(url);
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: "no-cors",
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }).then((res) => {
      var resJson = JSON.parse(res);
      console.log(resJson);
      return resJson;
    }).then((resJson) => {

    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("error");
    });
  }
```

Comment: You are making a GET request. There is no content in the request to describe the type of. `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }` is utter nonsense (and is actively harmful as it makes the request require a preflight OPTIONS request). Remove it.

Comment: what does the function `fetch` do?

Answer (score 3):

## Problem 1

Your URL is wrong.

> ```
> var url = 'api.apixu.com...
> ```

You forgot the scheme (`https://` or something should be at the front of that).

## Problem 2

You said `mode: "no-cors"` which means:

*I want to make this HTTP request, but I am not going to do anything that requires permission, so don't ask for permission, don't do anything that needs permission, and don't throw errors if I don't get permission*

Reading data from a different origin requires permission. Since you said you didn't want permission, you can't read the data and it fails silently.

Remove `mode: "no-cors"`. Use `mode: "cors"` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the only thing that worked for me was to send my request to a proxy server. 
This redirect did not work too:

```
const baseUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com'
```

After troubleshooting this issue for a long time, I redirected the response to another website and finally works.

```
const App = () => {
  ....

  const baseUrl = 'https://thingproxy.freeboard.io/fetch/';
```