# GET API working from browser but not through a FETCH call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I just put this in a script tag on a simple HTML page to run it for practicing `Promises` later on but the problem is it is giving me Bad Request reply.

```
  const postsPromise = fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/1', {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
  });
```

**BUT if** I copy paste the same URL in a browser, it works fine.
I also tried both `cors` and `no-cors` modes but it didn't make any difference.
Why?

P.S: I have seen this posts too but that doesn't answer it either: [Api working in browser but not in fetch javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51263059/api-working-in-browser-but-not-in-fetch-javascript)

Comment: We wouldn't be able to tell you.  This would be an error thrown by the API, so you should refer to its documentation.  You're probably missing a parameter or cookie or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because I need some sort of server to run `FETCH` on it.
For local experiments, `Browser Sync (` https://www.browsersync.io/ ) is an option.